# "Improve" vs. "Be improved"

Tags: grammar, verbs, differences, word-usage

I encountered the sentences someone posted on Facebook.

They posted: "I should be improved myself to be a better person."

I noticed that the sentence should be "I should improve myself to be a better person." instead. Since in this context, the verb should be non-reflexive, right?

And my questions are as followed,

1. Did they use the grammar correctly?
2. In which situations/contexts should "improve" be reflexive, or non-reflexive?

Could you provide examples of usage?

Comment: Your cited *I should be improved myself to be a better person* is syntactic garbage. Valid alternatives are *I should improve myself to be a better person* (where reflexive ***myself*** is optional) and *I should be improved to be a better person* (without ***myself***). They're both "clunky, weird" things to say (especially the latter, where the passive form implies that *someone else* must "improve" you), but at least they're syntactically valid.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Correctness of Grammar

No, the grammar is incorrect. Your suggestion of "I should improve myself to be a better person." is grammatically correct.

### 2. When to use a reflexive pronoun with "improve"

If there is no explicit object, then the understood object is the person(s) indicated by the subject:

> I should improve. (no explicit object) = I should improve myself. (I =
>   myself)
>
> They should improve (no explicit object). = They should improve themselves. (They = themselves)
>
> I will improve at basketball. = I will improve (myself) at basketball.

If there is an explicit object, and it's different from the person the subject indicates, then no reflexive pronoun is used:

> I should improve my score.
>
> They should improve their efficiency.

Comment: "I should improve myself to be a better person," could be interpreted two ways. "I should improve myself in order to be a better person," or "I should improve myself so as to be a better person," make the meaning clear.